# sqlalchemy python on join query - XOR behavior

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a join query in SQLAlchemy in Python where I want to result to contain all the records which have the same hash on two tables, but also if they have the same feature, and if not, take the record which has null value for a feature, so this is more like an XOR where there is a priority for the first value (if the feature exists always take that and not the null value, but if it doesn't exist take the null value)

```
query = query.join(
            some_table,
            sqlalchemy.and_(
                (some_table.hash == second_table.hash),
                sqlalchemy.or_(
                    (some_table.feature == second_table.feature),
                    (second_table.feature.is_(None)),
                ),
            ),
        )
```

However this obviously doesn't work since this `or_` always takes both. Is there a way to immitate the behavior which I asked for?
Also assume that second_table, although not mentioned was already joined before so I can use that in this query.

Comment: I don't know the SQLAlchemy syntax, but in raw SQL you would LEFT JOIN twice on the two conditions, then use `COALESCE()` to use one result as a fallback if the other fails.

Answer (score 0):

My example table names are regrettable but I think this works even without coalesce.  The inner join restricts all results to having matching hashes.
The outer join will just be NULL values if there is no match otherwise you will get matching features.  Depending on the table PK setup this could result in duplicates.

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "as"
    hash = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    feature = Column(String)


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bs'
    hash = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    feature = Column(String)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add_all([A(hash='1', feature='f1'), A(hash='2', feature='f2')])
    session.add_all([B(hash='1', feature='f2'), B(hash='2', feature='f2')])
    session.commit()


with Session(engine) as session:
    some_table = A.__table__
    second_table = B.__table__
    aliased_table = B.__table__.alias()

    query = select(
        some_table,
        aliased_table.c.feature)
    # Hash always must match
    query = query.join(
            second_table,
            some_table.c.hash == second_table.c.hash)
    # Hash and feature must match otherwise aliased table's columns are NULL.
    query = query.outerjoin(aliased_table, and_(
        some_table.c.hash == aliased_table.c.hash,
        some_table.c.feature == aliased_table.c.feature))
    print (session.execute(query).all())
```